# How I can write code in java to start with letter

Tags: java

how I can write program in java start by letter "a" and you can write letter or num like :
a
aa
a123
aa432a

the reguler exp for that
letter( letter|num )*

thanx.

Comment: Have you searched online for example Java programs using basic regular expressions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Regex would be `[a]([a]|[1-9])*` if this is what you are asking for.

Comment: yes. but i need it in program in java

Comment: @jedo and what stops you from doing so?

Comment: oh, I cant..... not I can .

Comment: Don't forget to include `0` among what will match.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you, now it's to you:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        //http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-input-from-console-java/
        System.out.println("Enter something here : ");

        try{
            BufferedReader bufferRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String input = bufferRead.readLine();

            boolean match = input.matches("[a]([a]|[1-9])*"); // maybe [a]([a-z]|[1-9])*

            System.out.println("Does it match? "+match);
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if we ues the  the conditional sentences( if, eles)  smaller and easier to program may be.